# How to filter GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter to obtain the Country result for both United states and canada

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, gmsplacepicker

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.city
        filter.country = "USA" || "CA"
```

how to get 2 country results in google autocomplete

Comment: Is it possible? any one can tell me

Answer (score 2):

If you check country property in `GMSAutocompleteFilter` class then you will found that it is `string` so I think you can't set multiple country in your filter. If it's allowing multiple country then it should be `array` or any `collection` instead of string! and in documentation also they haven't mentioned for multiple countries in filter! So, I think you can't set more than one country at a time in one filter!

Comment: you should refer [https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do using following syntax

`filter.country = "CA|country:US"`

reference link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. I would recommend using the web API, where you can send up to 5 ISO country codes in your query (see components under "optional parameters":

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete